# Unable to click on a button (Angular JS application)

Tags: angularjs

I'm unable to click on a button (Application built on Angular Js). My automation framework is existing one built on Java/Selenium WebDriver. I have tried with Xpath, CSS, etc still not working.

```
<button type="button" id="Button2" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-ng-click="StartWizard()" data-ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 ? StartWizard() : null">Import New File</button>
```

Script:

```
WebElement clickNextButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Import New File')]"));
        clickNextButton.click();
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[contains(text(),'Import New File')]"}
```

Could you please help me to resolve this. Please let me know if this can be resolved using `ngWebDriver`?

Comment: you can get the button from XPath? the value itself? the error appear with it can not locate your button.

Comment: I tried with locating the button directly, its not working  driver.findElement(By.id("Button2")).click();

Comment: Also tried with multiple options of identifying the locators, but no success

Comment: instead of find through the string find with the ID of the button.or maybe one of the possibility is that once your code run that time button is not visible. so try to set the initial time to visible and locate the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the ng-click function defined in the element:

```
String waitForAngularJs = "angular.element(\"#Button2\").scope().StartWizard();";
try {
            ExpectedCondition<Boolean> waitForAngular = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                    return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeAsyncScript(waitForAngularJs).equals(true);
                }
            };
            
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(myWebDriver, 60);
            wait.until(waitForAngular);
            
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Enjoy the code!

Comment: Thanks. But I'm facing the issue while trying to execute your code - org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: angular is not defined
JavaScript stack:
ReferenceError: angular is not defined